# pass parameters to codeigniters controller

Tags: codeigniter, parameters, get, controller

How do I pass to codeigniters controller a parameter via URL?
I use IgnitedTables to display jquery DataTable. Actually I use ajax to populate table (`cms_datatable()`) I would like to pass somehow a language parameter via url to can filter content on language

I have the following

```
public function cms($cms_lang = '') {

    $this->cms_lang = $this->session->userdata('cms_lang');
    if(isset($cms_lang)){
        $this->cms_lang['current_lang'] = $cms_lang;
    } else {
        $this->cms_lang['current_lang'] = 'de';
    }

        $tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="cms_table" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table table-striped table-primary table-condensed">');
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
        $this->table->set_heading('<input name="id[]" type="checkbox">', 'Title', 'SEF URL', 'Letztens bearbeitet', 'Status');
        $this->load->view('admin/admin', $this->data);
    }

    public function cms_datatable() {
    error_reporting(-1);
    // var_dump($this->cms_lang['current_lang']); returns NULL
    $this->datatables->select('id,title,sef_title, creation_date,status')            
            ->edit_column('title', '<a href="/admin/dashboard/edit_post/$1">$2</a>', 'id, title')
            ->unset_column('creation_date')
            ->add_column('creation_date', '<span class="label label-danger">$1</span>', 'creation_date')
            ->unset_column('status')
            ->add_column('status', get_buttons('$1'), 'id')
            ->from('ci_content')
            ->where('language', $this->cms_lang);
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

than I try to override the default value of variable `$lang` like

```
domain/admin/cms/en
```

but my `var_dump($lang)` shows the defualt value

routed as

```
$route['admin/cms']  = "admin/dashboard/cms";
$route['admin/cms/(:any)']  = "admin/dashboard/cms/$1";
```

Comment: CodeIgniter URLs are as such: `http://yoursite.com/controller/method/paramN`.  So you need to set your route to `admin/dashboard/cms/cms_datatable/$1`.

Comment: sorry I have to make some corrections

Comment: Have you considered [_remap()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) yet?

Comment: I got it working with a session id but is not the desired result thanks for the tip _remap it can be usefull for my frontend architecture

Answer (score 2):

your **controller** fn name is `cms_datatable` but you're not calling it.

Try using the url routes:

```
$route['admin/cms']         = "admin/dashboard/cms_datatable";
$route['admin/cms/(:any)']  = "admin/dashboard/cms_datatable/$1";
```

That route assumes that:

- **admin** is your folder
- **dashboard** is your controller
- **cms_datatable** is your controller fn

*Also*, re-reading your question, I am not sure why you want to pass language variables to EACH controller? Just set it in session and check it that way. Override the default if the session has a different language defined.  Having every controller check this is not good form.

Comment: thank you for your feedback I started to refactor the codes and I try to use a session variable to pass the language variable but on call doesn't seems to have value

Comment: if this answer solved / answered your current question don't forget to up vote / mark as solution.